# MAX id from Primary Key and add 1 in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to obtain the max primary key in the REDES table in order to add one but it's not working. I was also wondering if this would be the best way to do it and if it's secure.

```
// mysql inserting a new REDES field
//$redes_maxid = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(id_redessociales) AS id FROM REDES");
//$newmaxid = $redes_maxid + 1;
$redes_maxid = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT max(id_redessociales) AS id FROM REDES"));
$newmaxid = $redes_maxid[0] + 1;
mysql_query("INSERT INTO REDES(id_redessociales, facebook, twitter, linkedin, pinterest) VALUES ('$newmaxid', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL");
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is a HORRIBLE idea. **DO NOT USE IT**. Consider two people running this script at near identical times. They can BOTH get the **SAME** `max(id)`, both will try to insert with `max(id)+1`, and one of them will win - the other will lose with a duplicate key error.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using auto increment?

Comment: Well, actually I am, it's just that I'm new to this whole php-mysql thing and didn't know I could just insert with a NULL value. And the other reason why I was looking for an answer like this was because after doing this procedure, I have to use the newly created ID (the exact same number) into the USER table where the REDES id goes... so I have no idea what the best approach would be to do so without it becoming a problem in case several users want to register at the same time :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is very unsafe and wrong.

This is why we have `auto increment` fields in databases, just set the `id` field in your table to auto increment then when inserting a new row simply pass in `NULL` for the `id`, MySQL it will automatically do this increment for you safely.

[here's a link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) to the documentation

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what should I do then if I'm working with two separate tables? What's happening is that a record for REDES needs to be inserted before I insert a record in USER, because USER has a field that requires a REDES primary key. So which would be the best way to go  if several users wanted to register at the same time? Triggers, stored procedures? How can I make sure that the id being inserted in REDES will match the USER table when registering then? Thank you in advance...

Comment: 1-This is exactly why they're called RDBMS.
You need to lookup how to handle relations between your tables, you can always get the last insert id by accessing `$mysqli->insert_id`

2-You shouldn't be using the MySQL ext. , use MySQLi instead !

Answer (score 0):

You can get last id by ordering in descending order and limiting 1 row result

replace this line

```
$redes_maxid = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT max(id_redessociales) AS id FROM REDES"));
```

with

```
$redes_maxid = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT id_redessociales AS id FROM REDES order by id_redessociales DESC limit 1"));
```

Answer (score -1):

exactly what A.B said
But shouldn't you be making the ID's row in the database auto incremented?
you can set it to auto increment and when you insert a record just make the inserted ID `NULL`, the database will automaticly number it to the last ID+1

if you are ysing mySql then you can use this SQL statement

```
ALTER TABLE  `myTable` CHANGE  `id`  `id` TINYINT( 3 ) PRIMARY KEY UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```